# How to apply time based pagination for facebook marketing api `bulk read lead` edge

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.6

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/leads/v2.6

The output of `lead` edge is cursor based pagination. Can it be changed to time based pagination so i can apply time based filter. Current `bulk read` end point does not allow to use any time based modifiers like `since`, `until` only `limit` is allowed. I need to filter my result based on certain time period.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Scroll down in the documentation link you provided. You'll see a sample request ending in `&from_date=1482698431&to_date=1482784831`. Those parameters allow you to filter by lead date.